# Mapping ZFS pool to partition

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have two ZFS mount points/a ZFS pool in a FreeBSD 12.0 server, that I can see with df:

```
$ df -h | grep zroot
zroot/vms      196G    657M    195G     0%    /vms
zroot          195G     19K    195G     0%    /zroot
```

How can I know in which partition it is located? Can I know a little more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can know more about your ZFS pool with several commands:

```
$zpool status
 pool: zroot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zroot       ONLINE       0     0     0
      nvd0p4    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

As you can see, a ZFS pool zroot was created in the nvd0p4 partition.

You can also get a few more glimpses about the characteristics of the pool with the command `zpool list`:

```
$zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zroot   202G   657M   201G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

As `root`, you can also see the history of the ZFS pool usage:

```
$sudo zpool history
History for 'zroot':
2017-01-16.22:00:43 zpool create zroot /dev/nvd0p4
2017-01-16.22:48:59 zfs create -V16G -o volmode=dev zroot/linuxdisk0
2017-01-16.22:49:33 zfs destroy zroot/linuxdisk0
2017-01-17.20:59:04 zfs create -o mountpoint=/vms zroot/vms
2017-01-17.21:21:35 zfs create zroot/vms/testvm
2017-01-17.21:21:40 zfs create -sV 16G -o volmode=dev zroot/vms/testvm/disk0
2017-01-17.21:23:41 zfs destroy -rf zroot/vms/testvm
2017-01-30.22:24:59 zfs create zroot/vms/testvm
2017-01-30.22:25:04 zfs create -sV 16G -o volmode=dev zroot/vms/testvm/disk0
2017-01-30.22:35:15 zfs destroy -rf zroot/vms/testvm
```

You can also list the mounted ZFS filesystems:

```
$ zfs mount
zroot/vms                       /vms
zroot                           /zroot
```

ZFS has also support for snapshots, jails, and much more. See [man zfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zfs&sektion=8) and [man zpool](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool&sektion=8) for more details.

See also [ZFS Tutorials : Creating ZFS pools and file systems](http://thegeekdiary.com/zfs-tutorials-creating-zfs-pools-and-file-systems/)